# Indexerror: Tuple index out of rangle

Tags: python, arrays, tuples, index-error

The error that is given is that the tuple index is out of range. When I check the variables, the array is made in a [3,11] matrix but only filled in the first two rows. I'm not sure how to correct my code? Thanks

```
sigma_z = np.zeros((11,3)) 

for i in xrange(len(z)):
    for j in xrange(len(locx)):
        sigma_z[i-1,j-1] = (Mx[i-1]* locy[i-1])/ (Ix) - (My[i]* locx[j-1]) / (Iy)
```

Comment: No one can run your example as there are too many missing variables, like `z` and `locx` and `np` (I know what `np` means). Also, did you considered list comprehension? Also, a [3, 11] matrix? You mean a 3 x 11 matrix I think?!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a side effect because if `i=0` or `j=0` then `i-1` or `j-1` does not exist in the array, it is "out of range". Instead of `[i-1,j-1]` you should do `[max(0,i-1),max(0,j-1)]`. Or start your range with 1.